# Delete and select based on min (row_id)

Tags: sql-server-2008, min, sql-delete

I am trying to delete records by selecting `MIN(row_id)` from a table but the query is not working.
It is throwing this error:

> The `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

This is my query:

```
DELETE FROM c_dim
WHERE MIN(c_key) in (
    SELECT c_key, c_code
    FROM c_dim 
    WHERE flag = 'X' and c_code IN (
        SELECT c_code
        FROM c_dim
        WHERE flag = 'X'
        GROUP BY c_code HAVING COUNT(c_code)>1
    )
    ORDER BY c_code
)
```

Comment: And how exactly is the error message not descriptive enough?  Also, even when you remove the `Order By` you'll get another error complaining that you are selecting two values in your `In` `Select` statement.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with this (invalid) order by???

Comment: What are you trying to do with all these subqueries? The `order by` is not the only problem here.

Comment: How can i modify the query? I need to orderby the code.

Comment: Why do you need it? I can't see any logical difference.

Comment: I am trying to deduplicate the records after loading on to dim table.

Comment: Is just the subselect failing?  Try to get pieces working, and then you'll probably find the problem as you add the pieces together.

Comment: @juergen d whats the problem here then?

Comment: What value does the line `ORDER BY C_CODE)` have (aside from the last `)` if records are not being displayed or deleted based on their order?  Infact the line is what is causing the syntax error.  Remove `ORDER BY C_CODE` and it will remove this error. you have another however.

Comment: Subselect with out delete is working, when i add delete it throws the error

Comment: @xQbert the order by will bring two columns c_code and c_key

Comment: The `Order By` doesn't select columns... `Select` does.  Just delete the `Order By`, but you have other issues with this query.

Comment: what is the use `order by` in `subquery` without `Top` really it is not needed.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I have literally no idea what you are trying to achieve, and just stripping the errors out of your query is unlikely to be helpful. Can you describe in words, and preferably with example data exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all of your sub-queries can be replaced with this simple one

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c_code ORDER BY c_key) rn 
FROM c_dim
WHERE flag = 'X'
) 
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are almost certainly other ways to optimize this without all the subqueries, but the error message is pretty clear. To show why you are getting the error with a couple examples:

This should work because you would NOT have the ORDER BY within a subquery.

```
select c_key, c_code FROM c_dim where flag = 'X' 
 and c_code IN  
 (SELECT c_code 
  FROM c_dim 
  WHERE flag = 'X' 
  GROUP BY c_code HAVING COUNT(c_code) > 1 )
 ORDER BY c_code
```

This should NOT work because you have the ORDER BY within a subquery:

```
Select * FROM c_dim WHERE min(c_key)
 in(select c_key, c_code FROM c_dim where flag = 'X' 
 and c_code IN  
 (SELECT c_code 
  FROM c_dim 
  WHERE flag = 'X' 
  GROUP BY c_code HAVING COUNT(c_code) > 1 )
 ORDER BY c_code)
```

Therefore, to fix the DELETE as written, just take the ORDER BY out of the subquery, as it is completely unnecessary to the delete command:

```
DELETE FROM c_dim WHERE min(c_key)
 in(select c_key, c_code FROM c_dim where flag = 'X' 
 and c_code IN  
 (SELECT c_code 
  FROM c_dim 
  WHERE flag = 'X' 
  GROUP BY c_code HAVING COUNT(c_code) > 1 )
 )
```

Comment: Will try and check radshop.

Comment: This would still generate an error for selecting multiple values in the first `IN` statement.

Comment: In addition to selecting multiple columns in the subquery, you also can't use an aggregate function in the where clause in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose c_key is unique?

Try something like this:

```
delete from c_dim where c_key = min(c_key)
and rownum = 1;/* if you want the only first */
```

Now, I precise you what it's not a good delete request but she could make progress your issue.